# TIdTCPClient and MessageDlg in Android 6 with Delphi XE8

Tags: delphi, message, firemonkey, tcpclient, android-6.0-marshmallow

I try the next code in an android app in Delphi XE8;

```
function CheckInternet(idTCP: TIdTCPClient): boolean;
begin
      try
          idTCP.ReadTimeout := 4000;
          idTCP.ConnectTimeout := 4000;
          idTCP.Port := 80;
          idTCP.Host := 'google.com';
          idTCP.Connect;
          idTCP.Disconnect;
          result:=true;
      except
          result:=false;
      end;
end;
```

Then I check in main form if internet connection is available;

```
if Not CheckInternet(IdTCPClient1) then
                MessageDlg('Internet connection not available', TMsgDlgType.mtConfirmation, [TMsgDlgBtn.mbOK], 0,  procedure(const AResult: TModalResult) begin Application.Terminate; end);
```

Works fine in Android versions like 4.x and 5.x, but in Android version 6.x the program exits without display any message, otherwise if don't check for the internet connection, the message is displayed.
Please, Did anybody known about this issue?.

With an anonymous thread also does not works;

```
TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(procedure
         begin
             try
                IdTCPClient1.ReadTimeout := 4000;
                IdTCPClient1.ConnectTimeout := 4000;
                IdTCPClient1.Port := 80;
                IdTCPClient1.Host := 'google.com';
                IdTCPClient1.Connect;
                IdTCPClient1.Disconnect;
             except
                MessageDlg('Internet connection not available', TMsgDlgType.mtConfirmation, [TMsgDlgBtn.mbOK], 0,
                        procedure(const AResult: TModalResult) begin TThread.CurrentThread.Free; Application.Terminate; end);
             end;

         end).Start;
```

Updated code;

```
TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(procedure
         begin
                IdTCPClient1.ReadTimeout := 4000;
                IdTCPClient1.ConnectTimeout := 4000;
                IdTCPClient1.Port := 80;
                IdTCPClient1.Host := 'google.com';
                IdTCPClient1.Connect;
                IdTCPClient1.Disconnect;

                TThread.CurrentThread.OnTerminate := AnonymousThreadTerminate;

          end).Start;

procedure AnonymousThreadTerminate(Sender: TObject);
begin
        MessageDlg('Internet connection not available', TMsgDlgType.mtConfirmation, [TMsgDlgBtn.mbOK], 0,  procedure(const AResult: TModalResult) begin Application.Terminate; end);
end;
```

Many thanks and Regards.

Comment: There is nothing that Indy does that could be affecting `MessageDlg()` in this manner.  Something else is going on.  However, you are calling `CheckInternet()` in the main UI thread, which you should NOT be doing in the first place, since it is a blocking function. You can't block the main UI thread in Android, it is very sensitive to that and will kill your app if it blocks too long. You really should be performing this kind of logic in a worker thread instead of the main UI thread. You could have the worker thread notify the main UI thread if/when the connection state changes.

Comment: Thanks for comment and sorry for delay, but creating a simple project  with an unique form with only 2 components (TidTCPClient and TButton), using the lines of code above without any kind of threads or activity, checking for the internet connection in Onclick event of the button when there is not internet , produces the same result, app exits suddenly, testing in XE8 and Seattle and in two devices with Android 6.0.1. So I think that Delphi Indy components are incompatible with Android M. Does anybody have got that Indy works properly in Android M?.
Regards.

Comment: You are not listening. DO NOT CALL BLOCKING FUNCTIONS IN THE MAIN UI THREAD! *Period.* `TIdTCPClient.Connect()` is a blocking function. If you block the UI thread, *Android may kill your app*. Indy works just fine on Android in general, but regardless of whether there is an Internet connection or not, `Connect()` should be called in a worker thread on Android, not the UI thread.

Comment: Ok Remy, but I didn't get it to work without app exits, Do you have any working code or example?, Many thanks.

Comment: Please show your updated code. If you are using things correctly, the app should not be existing, unless maybe the main thread is raising an uncaught exception, or something like that.

Comment: Please you can find my updated code using an anomymous thread in Onclick event

Comment: You can't call `MessageDlg()` in a worker thread, you have to sync with the main UI thread to call it. And *never* call `TThread.CurrentThread.Free` at all. Besides, `CreateAnonymouseThread()` creates a thread with `FreeOnTerminate=True`, so you don't need to free it manually anyway. Do you have the same problem if you get rid of the `try/except` and display the `MessageDlg()` in the thread's `OnTerminate` event?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm very clumsy, the same result in updated code, always function `connect()` causes app exits, without `connect()` the message displays.